# importi.io : some data not imported or mixed in same column

Tags: regex, import.io

I'm using import.io's Magic API on this web page :

http://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichSarde.do?reprise=true&page=1&idSarde=SARDOBJT000007104398&ordre=null&nature=null&g=ls

Some types of info/fields are perfectly extracted.

But the extractor :

- mixes the NOR number field (example : NOR DEVL1502938A) with a number that represents the number of pages (example : 10) in a same column. Probably because they both are linked text (the tag is the following : 
  *a title="[...]" href="[...]"*)
- then mixes the bibliographic reference field (example : JO du 04/04/2015 texte : 0080;10 pages 6232/6241) with the NOR number field. It seems strange to me because the NOR systematically precedes the reference and they are not on the same line in the web page (there is a *br/* tag  before the bibliographic reference field)
- frequently fails to load the content of the text summary (example : (Application de l'art. R. 411-1 et s. du code de l'environnement - Abrogation de l'arrêté du 15 mai 1986 fixant sur tout ou partie du territoire national des mesures de protection des oiseaux représentés dans le département de la Guyane)) in one column. Instead it spreads it into various columns. I see it happens when a *em* tag is inserted after the *span class="noir"* tag. Example :

  **Application de l'art. R. 213-49-2 du code de l'environnement -* 
      Abrogation de l'arrêté du 10 août 2011 relatif à la définition du 
      périmètre de l'Etablissement public du Marais poitevin)*

I have tried using the New Extractor or working my away around through a special Google request results web page https://www.google.fr/search?q=PROTECTION+FAUNE+et+FLORE+SAUVAGES+site:legifrance.gouv.fr+filetype:pdf. To no avail. The Google web page alternative provides even worse results.

I would welcome any idea :

- on the reason why the second problem
- and how I can overcome the three problems on the Legifrance page.

Thanks a lot for reading this till the end :-)

PS : please note that I work primarily as a researcher. Although I can understand their logic, I am not familiar with Regex or Json. So if using them is needed, could you please either explain the logic behind or show enough a portion of the ideal code so that I can replicate it effectively ?

Comment: You hope too much from this kind of apps. The reason of the second problem is that import.io seems to group things by classname and do not take account of child elements.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte Thanks a lot for the comment. Any alternative app/software you can suggest that would be better suited to this work ?

Comment: I have tried to make learn import.io from *legifrance* link with the Extractor. Most of the time, it works well. The problem is that sometimes a *micro difference* can't be integrated with this learning approach without breaking the whole structure. I see two ways to solve the problem. The first consists to look carefully at the html source and to extract informations you want with a programming language. Other approach is more hybrid: you use import.io to get all needed (without loosing data) with the best structure you can, and you use a language/tool to correct the structure.

Comment: For the second option, note that the tool can be the advanced features of import.io. (I suggest to try the xpath way before the regex way)

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte Thanks a lot. Any good tutorial on the Web to learn about Xpath ? (I already have good tutorials for regex)

Comment: Difficult to find *the* perfect XPath tutorial. You can find a quick introduction here: http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/perl/excerpts/system-admin-with-perl/ten-minute-xpath-utorial.html . A lot of short examples here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (that can be useful too). The wikipedia (clear and useful): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath . A more general tutorial: http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathtutorial.php . The official xpath recommendations: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/